# FHIR : How to Handle Resource within Resource?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am new in FHIR, I want to develop FHIR's Server in C#, Please help me how to handle Resource within Resource. For Example in Encounter Resource, (partOf : Resource(Encounter)), similarly in Organization resource there is Organization etc, I am trying but it goes to Infinite LOOP. Not proceed to next classes.I am retrieving data from Database for time being... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the definition of a Resource and you see an element with a datatype of Resource(X) (like the example you mentioned, partOf: Resource(Encounter)) this means that resource *references* another Resource (in this case, an Encounter). The 'partOf' element is actually an URL (or rather, an uri) pointing to another resource somewhere else on the same RESTful endpoint (or within the same message or document if you are using those constructs). So, this is more like a 'foreign key' in "traditional" database technology.

So, yes, Organizations can reference Organizations, Encounters can reference Encounters!
In my tutorial on FHIR (available at http://www.slideshare.net/ewoutkramer/fhir-tutorial-morning), you can find some examples and background from slide 29 on. Basically, this is what a reference looks like:

```
<partOf>
  <reference value='http://spark.furore.com/fhir/Organizaiton/4433EF-33'/>
  <display value="Some other organization"/>
</partOf>
```

Note that this is very different from containment.  If you take a look at the same Encounter resource (at http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/encounter.html), you'll see a component 'Hospitalization', this component is nested within the resource (so *no* reference), as indicated by the "closed diamond" shape in the UML.

In case you need an example of how to implement a .NET FHIR server, please take a look at our open-source implementation here: http://www.github.com/furore-fhir/spark. Also, be sure to get the .NET helper API's via NuGet (just look for FHIR).

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the infinite loop, it's entirely possible for references to loop back to an initiating resource.  While resources don't generally point directly to themselves, traversing a chain of resources and winding back up at the starting resource is quite possible.  Systems that traverse links will need to account for this potential looping.